# problem occurred contacting the resource controller

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm using IBM Cloud Node-Red and I'm trying to connect speech to text to my Node Red instance. I keep getting the following message "BXNUI0033E: The 'node-red-speechtotext-1590542039496' service wasn't added to the 'Node RED' app because a problem occurred contacting the resource controller. 
Try again later. If you see this message again, go to the IBM Cloud status page to check whether a service or component has an issue. If the problem continues, go to IBM Cloud Support."  Any suggestions?